# How to: Export a recordset as a semicolon separated csv file in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, export-to-csv

Exporting a recordset to an external csv file generates a csv file which is comma separated in Mysql workbench. Is there a way to make it export to a semicolon separated csv file instead?.

I tried looking if there is some settings in Mysql workbench which can be changed to make the csv as semicolon separated but couldnt find. Is the exported csv file comma separated by default and cannot be changed or is there a workaround?

Comment: You can execute SELECT..INTO OUTFILE statement to get desired CSV-file. There are many useful options, column separator also can be changed - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.run the query for output in Workbench

2.select the following button for export to records 
   [image]

3. Insert the following values

[image]

4. Click on export. The records would be exported to a csv file mentioned in the "File Path"

Comment: The key point is that the "File Format" there is a dropdown. Choose "CSV (;separated" instead of "CSV" to use ";" instead of ",".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. When you are exporting the result set, choose "CSV (; separated)" instead of "CSV" as the output format. See the [related documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-results.html) (and a screenshot).

Alternatively, the table "Table Data Export Wizard" also has an option to use ";" as the field separator. Get there by right-clicking on a table in the schema viewer.